# reset button to set default values in select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm becoming really crazy about this issue. I'm trying to do a button that resets all my select boxes to default value. I've tried various methods and all of them fail. I don't get any error in browser console neither. I'm going to show you a few different methods I've tried.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="main-search-results">
  <select name="provincia" id="select-filter-2">
    <option value="cualquier_provincia" selected="selected">Cualquier provincia</option>
    <option value="a_coruña">A Coruña</option>
    <option value="alava">Alava</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is one of the ways I've tried to solve it

```
$("reset").click(function() {
  $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

This is my how I request the js and css links. Notice the select-custom.js is where I build the selectors with ('#select-filter-2').selectmenu() This the file doesn't let me reset selects. If I remove it works great.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\font-awesome\css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/select-custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I've implemented and works ok. Thanks to A.J. that helped me with his answer.

```
$(function(){

  $('select').selectmenu();

  function cleanFilters() {
    $('select').val('default');
    $('select').selectmenu('refresh');
  }  

  $('#reset').click(function(){
    cleanFilters();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function(){
     $("#reset")
     .on("click", function(){
    $("#select-filter-2")
       .find("option[value=cualquier_provincia]")
       .prop("selected", "selected");
     });

 });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0snsgkra/) obviously only resets one of them. But if you apply a class like `.default` then you can go:

```
 $("#select-filter-2")
       .find("option.default")
       .prop("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9yeup7gk/5/):

```js
$("#reset").on("click",function(){
$("#select-filter-2").prop('selectedIndex',0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="provincia" id="select-filter-2">
    <option value="cualquier_provincia" selected="selected">Cualquier provincia</option>
    <option value="a_coruña">A Coruña</option>
    <option value="alava">Alava</option>
  </select>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r2b2ga9k/1/) of more than one select box

```js
$("#reset").on("click", function() {
  $("select").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="provincia" id="select-filter-2">
  <option value="cualquier_provincia" selected="selected">Cualquier provincia</option>
  <option value="a_coruña">A Coruña</option>
  <option value="alava">Alava</option>
</select>
<select name="provincia">
  <option value="cualquier_provincia" selected="selected">Cualquier provincia</option>
  <option value="a_coruña">A Coruña</option>
  <option value="alava">Alava</option>
</select>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

**Update**:

As mentioned in comment That if 1st index is not selected by default then, use this:

```js
$("#reset").on('click',function(){
    if($("#select-filter-2").find("option[selected]").length > 0){
        var s =$("#select-filter-2").find("option[selected]").val(); //selected="selected" and just selected both are valid so keep it generic
        $("#select-filter-2").val(s);
    }else{
        $("#select-filter-2").prop('selectedIndex',0); // in case no option is set selected then fall back to first option
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-search-results">
  <select name="provincia" id="select-filter-2">
    <option value="cualquier_provincia" >Cualquier provincia</option>
    <option value="a_coruña" selected="selected" >A Coruña</option>
    <option value="alava">Alava</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Update as per Op comment:

Use following to [refresh you menu](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh).

```
$( "#select-filter-2" ).selectmenu( "refresh" );
```

Comment: This will work only on a assumption that the 0 index is always selected by default.

Comment: @Varun: Absolutely right. And this is the standard mostly. Even in op has `selected`, is on first index.

Comment: @Varun: I have updated the post. I hope every scenario is covered now. :)

Comment: Ok I know what is going on here. It doesn't work any of all your answers and that was weird. I've realized that is because I'm buiding the selector with JQuery selectmenu $('#select-filter-2').selectmenu() If I remove that js the reset button works like a cosmic puzzle of course, but I need that js to build and style the selects. So if anybody has a solution for that...would be great¡¡ I update my answer to you can see how I'm requesting js

Comment: @DavidSoler: I have updated the answer as per  jquer-ui. It spuld work.

Comment: Thank you A.J. That's been really helpfull. It's working right now but I've had to add $('select').val('default') just before the refresh option. I answer my question to you can see the final solution

Comment: @david soler: good to hear that you found a solution n it is working now :)

Comment: @DavidSoler: Now that you have found the solution, accept your answer :) . It will help people coming forward looking for answer to similar question :)

Comment: When I try to accept my answer it says that I cannot accept my answer in 19 hours

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$("#res").on('click',function(){
    var s =$("#select-filter-2").find("option[selected='selected']").val();
    $("#select-filter-2").val(s);
});
```

Note:`res` is the id of a regular button.
Also i have done for one,you can generalize for many selects,probably by using a common class.

JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/vLgxvkyk/